# I am trying add a background image in css, but I'm getting the following error

Tags: html, css, sass, google-web-designer

Failed to compile.

**ERROR :**

> ./src/app/shopping-list/shopping-edit/shopping-edit.component.css
>   Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:
>   D:\demoApp\src\app\shopping-list\shopping-edit\shopping-edit.component.css:98:26:
>   Can't resolve 'assets/header.png' in
>   'D:\demoApp\src\app\shopping-list\shopping-edit'

**CODE :**

```
   96 | }
   97 | .section-testimonials{
>  98 |     background-image:url(assets/header.png); ;
      |                          ^
   99 | }
  100 |
```

Comment: use `url("")` with quotes

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes and a forward slash in the location:

```
   96 | }
   97 | .section-testimonials{
>  98 |     background-image:url("./assets/header.png"); ;
      |                          
   99 | }
  100 |
```